# DecoView dependency not wotking

Tags: java, android

I am working on my project for final year and cant seem to get my dependency working?

```
implementation 'com.github.bmarrdev:android-DecoView-charting:v1.2'
```

This is the dependency I am using as indicated from https://github.com/bmarrdev/android-DecoView-charting

I would really appreciate anyone's help with this.
Thanks in advance

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

I have added it now
Thanks

Comment: looks like you have missed the Step 1 of integration guide in the instructions.

Comment: I have tried that already and it makes no difference, it still doesn't allow the dependency

Comment: then you probably added it to wrong place. It's impossible to say because you didn't show it

Comment: I have updated the file above

Comment: you should add that repository to your module `build.gradle`, not to the project one. Or add it to `allprojects`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```